# How to add Image button with stringbuilder in c#?

Tags: c#, imagebutton, stringbuilder

I want to add image button in the c# code behind. I'm working with stringBuilder to create my html tags in code behind. I want to add image button with the html tag. How do I do this?

```
    StringBuilder sbWorkMap = new StringBuilder();
    IList<WorkMapNode> workMapNode = 
    WorkMapNode.GetByWorkMapModuleId(item.WorkMapModuleId); 

    foreach (var node in workMapNode) {

    ImageButton imgBtn = new ImageButton();
    imgBtn.ID = node.WorkMapNodeId.ToString();
    imgBtn.ImageUrl = "~/images/check.jpg";

    if (node.Url != null) {
            sbWorkMap.Append("<h4><a href='" + node.Url + "'>" + node.Name + "</a></h4>");
    }
    else {
            sbWorkMap.Append("<h4>" + node.Name + "</h4>");
    }
}

// I'm adding the string builder to Place holder control
phWorkMap.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(sbWorkMap.ToString()));
```

**Question**

How do I add the imgBtn to sbWorkMap? I want to add image button for every node I create!

**Should look like this**

ImageButton1 Node 1

ImageButton2 Node 2

ImageButton3 Node 3

Comment: ImageButtons are server-side controls, so you can't render them simply by outputting HTML. Are you planning to associate server-side code to click events on the image button, or do you really just want to output an image?

Comment: Yes, I do want to associate server-side click event.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing. Shouldn't you add the image button by using the the asp-object-model in Page_Load instead of using a StringBuilder?

Comment: Well, what I'm trying to do here is, I want to add multiple image button! Basically if see my code every node I want to add an image button.

Comment: you can load control (`ImageButton`) dynamically, you can have `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder..>` and load `ImageButton` inside and add 'Event' to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to render HTML, you can add an image directly to a page:

```
ImageButton imgBtn = new ImageButton();

imgBtn.ImageUrl = @"~images\April.jpg";

this.Form.Controls.AddAt(0, imgBtn);
```

Index is at what location the image should be placed.  You can also place it inside of other controls.

Comment: I want to add image button for every node that I create.

Comment: You can create and add as many controls as your heart desires.

Comment: It works! but how do I place it beside every node? Index is not working for me!

Comment: I found the solution, instead add to the form I add to the place holder directly.